# AngularJS: Using LoDash to total a ng-grid column

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I am trying to use the _.reduce() method in lodash to total the inputs of a column in ng-grid.

I have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bo7E9Y?p=preview) with what I thought would be the proper code but if I uncomment that code, the plunker breaks, so I am currently returning a static.

What I need is for the age field on the Total row to update any time one of the other ages is modified.

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.constant('_', window._)
  .run(function ($rootScope) {
      $rootScope._ = window._;
  });

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, _) {

  function getAge(){
    /*_.reduce($scope.myData, 
      function(age, num) {
        return age + num;
      });
    return totalAge;*/
    return 230;
  }

    $scope.myData = [
      {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
      {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
      {name: "Jacob", age: 74},
      {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
      {name: "Enos", age: 34},
      {name: "Total", age: getAge()}
    ];
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'myData', 
      enableCellSelection: true,
      enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
      enableRowSelection: false,
      columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}]
    };
});
```

and view:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues; firstly you should probably look into using the built in ng-grid footer to show totals (A quick google search for ng-grid footer example will help). The only other way would be to supply a CellTemplate for the Age column, and have that template call a function on the scope of your controller to add up the values. However, this celltemplate would be used for each cell in the second column, so you'd need additional logic to only sum values if you are being invoked under the context of that final cell. More reason to use the footer template ng-grid provides :-)

I've [modified your code so that it works](http://bit.ly/1v1l4Yo), but you get the summed total in every cell, which is not what you are after, and is why 'Total' should not be considered 'just another row' in your data.

Comment: thanks for this ... I did not know about the footer so I will google now ... I am trying to create an excel spreadsheet like experience for an analyst